# MySQL ORDER BY field with a toggle

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql5

I have a mysql result that looks like this:

```
| compare | field1 | field2 | much more |
-----------------------------------------
|   new   |    x1  |    y   | ...       |
|   old   |    x1  |    y   | ...       |
|   old   |    x2  |    y   | ...       |
|   new   |    x2  |    y   | ...       |
```

The Query searches for differences of two tables (new and old) and orders it by field1 (with lots more fields, but lets make it simple here). So, the query is returning everything correct but one thing: In the query, there is a UNION ALL with FIRST fetch old, then UNION ALL it to SECOND new.

What i want to have is a result, where my "compare" has ALWAYS FIRST an old and then the new. But see my result, sometimes i get new first and this will break the rest of the code.

I tried it with

```
ORDER BY FIELD(compare, 'old', 'new'), ...
```

but it did not work.

Anyone with an idea?
Result should be like this:

```
| compare | field1 | field2 | much more |
-----------------------------------------
|   old   |    x1  |    y   | ...       |
|   new   |    x1  |    y   | ...       |
|   old   |    x2  |    y   | ...       |
|   new   |    x2  |    y   | ...       |
```

### Edit #1:

Here is the complete Query for this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(compareTables) AS 'table',
  CONCAT(ObjNr, PFKt, WhgNr, DatVon, AdrNr, KEY_Firma) AS 'primary',
  ObjNr,
  PFKt,
  WhgNr,
  DatVon,
  DatBis,
  AdrNr,
  KEY_Firma,
  Info,
  PKto,
  FI_MieterPKto,
  PFktArtEigMiet,
  ST_SchlAustriaPKto,
  inaktiv,
  inaktivBis
FROM ((SELECT
      'old' AS compareTables,
      ObjNr,
      PFKt,
      WhgNr,
      DatVon,
      DatBis,
      AdrNr,
      KEY_Firma,
      Info,
      PKto,
      FI_MieterPKto,
      PFktArtEigMiet,
      ST_SchlAustriaPKto,
      inaktiv,
      inaktivBis
    FROM table_old.PF_PFkt) UNION ALL (SELECT
      'new' AS compareTables,
      ObjNr,
      PFKt,
      WhgNr,
      DatVon,
      DatBis,
      AdrNr,
      KEY_Firma,
      Info,
      PKto,
      FI_MieterPKto,
      PFktArtEigMiet,
      ST_SchlAustriaPKto,
      inaktiv,
      inaktivBis
    FROM table_new.PF_PFkt)) AS compareTables
WHERE 'primary' IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ObjNr,
         PFKt,
         WhgNr,
         DatVon,
         DatBis,
         AdrNr,
         KEY_Firma,
         Info,
         PKto,
         FI_MieterPKto,
         PFktArtEigMiet,
         ST_SchlAustriaPKto,
         inaktiv,
         inaktivBis
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ObjNr, PFKt, WhgNr, DatVon, AdrNr, KEY_Firma
```

and part of the result
[image: result_of_query]

Answer (score 3):

First order by `field1`. Then order by `compare` descending, to get *old* before *new*.

```
ORDER BY field1, compare DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sry. field1 will have more than once the same content (for example, field 1 is an planeid with value 10, when having multiple changes to the same plane, it appears more often).

Comment: I tried this out and it breaks the ordering of a new and old belonging together

Comment: Seems like you need better sample data, to illustrate the actual problem.

Comment: Just imagine, that in my first post, field1 can have the same data, also field2, but the change is in field_x and i do not know how many fields coming (it's a dynamic sql generator for several problems)

Comment: This is definitely correct answer to the question you asked above, if it does not help then you didn't ask the question right. You should give a better sample data

Comment: Made an edit #1 for my question, hope, this will help to get it right ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
order by field1, field2, (compare = 'OLD') DESC
```

Comment: No, sry, this will give me all "old" first and then all "new", but this must toggle with always "old" first ;)

Comment: @Paladin . . . No, that is not what this does.  The condition on `compare` is the *third* key in the `order by`.

Comment: I have the SQL here in my Editor and i fired it with your change on third pos of orderby, the result was all "old" first and after that all "new"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
order by (field1, field2 DESC), compare = 'OLD' DESC
```

Comment: this does not work, i get an error message
```Operand should contain 1 column(s)```